# I have 3 variables (Model code, Q'ty, Date) finding the same Model code, Date in another sheet and set value to Q'ty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 variables 1. Model Code (**matNo**) 2. Quantity (**q'ty**) 3. **Dates**
These 3 variables are in the sheet called "**CB Cal**". And I have another sheet called "**Auto M**".

I want the program to match **matNo** and **Dates** from "**CB Cal**" with **matNo** and **Dates** in "**Auto M**" sheet then input the **q'ty** in the sheet.

Now I'm thinking of using Loop because I have a lot of matNo (about 100+ matNo). But I couldn't figure what is the best way. I'm thinking of using array but haven't tried it yet. Some help or guide would be very appreciated.

Here are photos of my sheets I circled the 3 variables in the picture.

CB Cal sheet[image]

Auto M sheet[image]

I will have more conditions in the future but I just need to know the appropriate command to use.
Here is my useless code

```js
function autoCalCB3() {                      //Looping through "C"
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var getCB = app.getSheetByName("CB Cal");
  var getAutoM = app.getSheetByName("Auto M");
  var i;
  //var matnoArray = [];
  
  for (i=4; i<=4; i) {                   // BIGGEST LOOP
      x = getCB.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      if (x != "") {
        matno = x;
        Logger.log(matno);
        for (j=2; j<=32; j++) { //Vanning Q'ty date loop
          VanQty = getCB.getRange(i,3).offset(3,j).getValue();
          VanDate = getCB.getRange(i,3).offset(4,j).getValue();
          Logger.log(VanQty);
          Logger.log(VanDate);
          var alloVanQty = getAutoM.getRange(4,23+j).setValue(VanQty);
            
        }
        i = i+5;
      }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for comments/help.

Comment: What is exactly your problem in this question? Do MatNo and Dates from one sheet have to be **both** a match to those in the other sheet? Doing two ```for``` loops would work. You could also aternatively use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to return all the values in the range of MatNo and Dates and then use the returned array to iterate through each range.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll try learning and doing what you said.